# "dialer.exe" in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, phone, telephony

I'm having trouble answering phone calls with dialer.exe.  There seems to be no option to answer an incoming call.  I am using a windows 7 netbook with modem addon in israel and trying to accept incoming calls from USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialer no longer supports receiving phone calls. You'll have to find some sort of 3rd party software to accomplish this, and it's likely that you will have trouble getting your sound card working with the modem. There's not much of a market for this... but I did find one program that might work: http://www.mycallsoft.com/

Comment: I thought that there was a pretty popular program for computer phone calls...I think it is called Skype or some such...

Comment: @EBGreen Skype won't work through a modem. It's a great solution if OP is willing to ditch the modem though.

Comment: I need it to work without internet access. sorry for not specifying.

Comment: @user1015230 - So update the question.

Comment: @Ramhound he says it right in the question `I am using a windows 7 netbook with modem addon in israel and trying to accept incoming calls from USA.`, Seemed obvious to me that he was trying to do a direct PC to PC connection over a modem.